# Split word in two pairs but with little change

Tags: python, string, list, if-statement, split

I need help with given task -

> Split the string into pairs of two characters. If the string contains an odd number of characters, then the missing second character of the final pair should be replaced with an underscore ('_').

```
def split_pairs(a):
    if len(a)%2==0:
        a.split(', ', 2)
    else:
        a.split(', ', 2)
        a.replace(items[2][-1] , '_')
        return a
```

Comment: And the problem with your code is?

Comment: Please include example input and expected output. You say "pairs of two characters" but your code is splitting on `", "`. That's a different thing. Is the input pairs of text separated by commas?

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming a particular separator. Instead of making this assumption, you can loop over starting indices (with a step of 2), and extract the relevant substrings. Concatenate a `_` to the final one if needed:

```
def split_pairs(a):
    out = [a[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(a), 2)]
    if len(out[-1]) == 1:
        out[-1] += '_'
    return out

print(split_pairs('Hello'),
      split_pairs('world!'))
```

This gives:

```
['He', 'll', 'o_'] ['wo', 'rl', 'd!']
```